# trigger computed to be recalculated when observableArray element property is changed

Tags: knockout.js

I have `observableArray` with elements (elements are not observables, but some unobservable objects). I have also `computed` variable that depands on `observableArray`. If I push elements into array, then everything works (I mean - computed variable is recalculated).

However, if I change some properties of observableArray single items, then computed is not recalculated:

```
var myObsArr = ko.observableArray();

// myObsArr is loaded using ko.mapping.fromJS with data from server
// but I am using custom mapping that won't create observables for observableArray items, part of my custom mapping (the one that corresponds to observable item) is something like this:
 create: function (options) {
    // here are some manipulations and
    return ko.toJS(options.data); //doesn't create observables for observableArry items
}

var computedArr = ko.computed(function() {
   var t = self.myObsArr();
   // do manipulations on t and return manipulated array
});

// later I need to change some elements of observable array, for example:
myObsArr[0].Month = "Mar"; //doesn't trigger computed to be recalculated
```

How to trigger computed to be recalculated when any object inside observable array is changed?

Comment: If `myObsArr` was loaded with `ko.mapping.fromJS` then `Month` sould be normally an ko.observable because of the mapping. So you should set with `myObsArr[0].Month("Mar");` and if you accessing `Month()` in your computed then it should also be udated. Otherwise call `valueHasMutated` after changing the `Month`:  `myObsArr[0].Month = "Mar"; myObsArr.valueHasMutated();`

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my description. I am doing custom mapping that doesn't create observables for array elements. But probably I can change the logic and make all items observable, will it help? or Can I use valueHasMutated without converting Month and other properties to observables?

Comment: `myObsArr.valueHasMutated();` will work as long as you don't forget to call it after every time you change something in the array. So you would be probably better to convert the properties which you use in the computed to observables because then you get the change tracking for free.

Comment: valueHasMuted helped me, this is the answer that works for me. As it is a bit urgent, I will leave as it is with valueHasMuted, but then later probably I will changed to observables...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `valueHasMutated` method on your `myObsArr` after modifying one of its elements. It will trigger the knockout dependency tracking and your `computedArr` will be notified about the change:

```
myObsArr[0].Month = "Mar";
myObsArr.valueHasMutated();
```

However you have to remember to call this every time you change an item in array so you are probably better to turn your `Month` into an `ko.observable` because in this case the ko change tracking will pick the changes automatically and it will notify your computed without any additional code.