# Knockout.js | Observable array only triggers when last element changes

Tags: javascript, c#, knockout.js

**The Scenario**

I have multiple input fields. The fields are NOT allowed to be empty. If any field is empty, I want to show some sort of error message.

---

**The issue**

The issue I am dealing with is that I have an observable array populating some inputs through a knockout foreach for the view.

Everything loads, displays, and saves properly, however, my validation (which is a computed) is only called when the last element in the observable array changes and not when any of the other elements change.

I found [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23253469/trigger-computed-to-be-recalculated-when-observablearray-element-property-is-cha), but OP's issue here was that he/she did not have their value as an observable which is not my problem as my value is wrapped as an observable.

---

**The Code**

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a2Lkmf0y/37/)

Here's the code:

**View**

```
<div data-bind="with: itemsModel">
  <label data-bind="text: validMessage">Totally valid</label>
  <div data-bind="foreach: items">
    <div>
      <label>Item: </label>
      <input type="text " data-bind="value: name " />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function ItemModel(item) {
  self = this;
  self.item = item;

  self.name = ko.observable(item.name);

  self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.name() && self.name().length <= 256;
  });
}

function ItemsModel(itemsModel) {
  var self = this;
  self.itemsModel = itemsModel;

  self.items = ko.observableArray([
    new ItemModel(itemsModel.items[0]),
    new ItemModel(itemsModel.items[1]),
    new ItemModel(itemsModel.items[2])
  ]);

  // This is only getting called when the last element in self.items changes
  self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    var isValid = true;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      isValid = isValid && self.items()[i].isValid();
    }

    return isValid;
  });

  self.validMessage = ko.computed(function() {
    if (self.isValid()) {
      return "Totally Valid";
    }

    return "Totally NOT Valid";
  });
}

function ViewModel(data) {
  var self = this;
  self.data = data;

  self.itemsModel = ko.observable(new ItemsModel(data.itemsModel));
}

var modelData = {
  itemsModel: {
    items: [{
      name: "Item One"
    }, {
      name: "Item Two"
    }, {
      name: "Item Three"
    }]
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel(modelData));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not declaring your first `self` locally, so it's global.

```
function ItemModel(item) {
  self = this;
```

should be

```
function ItemModel(item) {
  var self = this;
```

Comment: OMG... You're a genius! I can't believe I missed that, but I guess it's from looking at too much knockout haha. If I could give you a cookie, I would, but I guess the accepted answer will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

Knockout way to determine when a computed need to be updated is a little tricky, you need to executed at least once every observable to get them registered.

Try something like this.

```
  self.isValid = ko.computed(function() {
    var isValid = true;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
      //if isValid is false second part will not executed
      //isValid = isValid && self.items()[i].isValid(); 

      isValid = self.items()[i].isValid() && idValid;
    }

    return isValid;
  });
```

I'd have a similar case here https://stackoverflow.com/a/38131131/2233835

Hope it helps!

Comment: Though this isn't the cause of my issue, this is a very valid point. I'll give you an upvote for making a good point.